# How to pass the ALM/QC test plan folder path in excel macro to fetch steps for scripts in a particular folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel macro to fetch steps for scripts in ALM/QC test plan. Right now, it is fetching steps for all the scripts and it takes around 5-6 hours. I want to fetch steps for scripts in a particular folder. I am having trouble on how to pass the folder path.

Request to please help me on how to pass the folder path. Also, if possible suggest on how to fetch steps only for a particular script.

I tried 2 ways to give folder path. Both didn't worked.

Way 1: fpath = "Subject/Release 1/System Test/SCR 12345  Inbound"

Way 2: fpath = "^&#92Subject&#92Release 1&#92System Test&#92SCR 12345  Inbound#92^"

Below is the macro code:

```
Function EmportTestCases()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim QCConnection
    Dim sUserName, sPassword
    Dim sDomain, sProject
    Dim TstFactory, TestList
    Dim TestCase
'Create QC Connection Object to connect to QC
    Set QCConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")

'    sUserName = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter ALM username", Title:="ENTER ALM USERNAME", Default:="")

    sUserName = "username"
    sPassword = "xxxxxxx"

'   sPassword = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Password", Title:="ENTER PASSWORD", Default:="")

    QCConnection.InitConnectionEx "QC url till QCBIN"
'Authenticate your user ID and Password
    QCConnection.Login sUserName, sPassword
'Quit if QC Authentication fails
    If (QCConnection.LoggedIn <> True) Then
        MsgBox "QC User Authentication Failed"
        End
    End If
    sDomain = "PROJDOMAIN"
    sProject = "PROJ"
'Login to your Domain and Project
    QCConnection.Connect sDomain, sProject
'Quit if login fails to specified Domain and Project
    If (QCConnection.AuthenticationToken = "") Then
        MsgBox "QC Project Failed to Connect to " & sProject
        QCConnection.Disconnect
        End
    End If
'Now successful connection is made to QC
'Get the test factory
    Set TstFactory = QCConnection.TestFactory
' Your QC Project Path for which you want to download
' the test cases.
    fpath = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Folder path", Title:="ENTER FOLDER PATH", Default:="")
'    fpath = "Subject/Release 1/System Test/SCR 12345  Inbound"
' Entered the above fpath for the folder path.

    Set myfilter = TstFactory.Filter()
    myfilter.Filter("TS_SUBJECT") = fpath
'Get a list of all test cases for your specified path
    Set TestList = myfilter.NewList()

'Format the header before downloading the test cases
            With ActiveSheet
           .Range("B5").Select
            With .Range("B4:H4")
           .Font.Name = "Arial"
           .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
           .Font.Size = 10
           .Font.Bold = True
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
           .Width = 20
       End With
        .Cells(4, 2) = "Subject (Folder Name)"
        .Cells(4, 3) = "Test Name (Manual Test Plan Name)"
        .Cells(4, 4) = "Description"
        .Cells(4, 5) = "Status"
        .Cells(4, 6) = "Step Name"
        .Cells(4, 7) = "Step Description(Action)"
        .Cells(4, 8) = "Expected Result"
       Dim Row
        Row = 5 '- set the data row from 5
'loop through all the test cases.
        For Each TestCase In TestList
            .Cells(Row, 2).Value = TestCase.Field("TS_SUBJECT").Path
            .Cells(Row, 3).Value = TestCase.Field("TS_NAME")
'QC stores description in html format. So before storing it
'in to excel, StripHTML() will remove all HTML tags and put
'texts only. Also new line tag <br> is replaced with new line
'character chr(10) in excel so that all the new line texts appears properly
           .Cells(Row, 4).Value = StripHTML(Replace(TestCase.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION"), _
 "<br>", Chr(10)))
'  .Cells(Row, 4).Value = TestCase.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION")
            .Cells(Row, 5).Value = TestCase.Field("TS_EXEC_STATUS")
'Get the DesignStepFactory for the this testcase
            Dim DesignStepFactory, DesignStep, DesignStepList
            Set DesignStepFactory = TestCase.DesignStepFactory
            Set DesignStepList = DesignStepFactory.NewList("")
'Check if design steps exists for the test
            If DesignStepList.Count <> 0 Then
'loop for all the steps for this test case
                For Each DesignStep In DesignStepList
                    .Cells(Row, 6).Value = DesignStep.StepName
                    .Cells(Row, 7).Value = StripHTML(Replace(DesignStep.StepDescription, _
 "<br>", Chr(10)))
  '                  .Cells(Row, 7).Value = DesignStep.StepDescription


                    .Cells(Row, 8).Value = StripHTML(Replace(DesignStep.StepExpectedResult, _
 "<br>", Chr(10)))
  '                  .Cells(Row, 8).Value = DesignStep.StepExpectedResult
                    Row = Row + 1
                Next 'next Step
            End If
            ' release the design step objects
            Set DesignStepFactory = Nothing
            Set DesignStep = Nothing
            Set DesignStepList = Nothing
        Next ' Next test case
    End With
    'Release the object
    Set DesignStepFactory = Nothing
    Set DesignStep = Nothing
    Set DesignStepList = Nothing
    Set TstFactory = Nothing
    Set TestList = Nothing
    Set TestCase = Nothing
    QCConnection.Disconnect
    MsgBox ("All Test cases are downloaded with Test Steps")
End Function

 Function StripHTML(sInput As String) As String
 Dim RegEx As Object
 Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

 Dim sOut As String
 With RegEx
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = True
   .MultiLine = True
   .Pattern = "<[^>]+>" 'Regular Expression for HTML Tags.
  End With

  sOut = RegEx.Replace(sInput, "")
  StripHTML = sOut
  Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Folder path in QC filters use backslash... try backslash ().